# Models and Views for base.html page

Tags: django, python-3.x

views.py

def HomeView(request):

```
    slider = SliderImage.objects.all()
    gallary = GallaryImage.objects.all()
    lastimage = gallary.latest('id')
    return render(request,'homepage/homepage.html', {'slider': slider, 
                  'gallary': gallary, 'lastimage': lastimage})
```

urls.py

urlpatterns = [

```
    url(r'^$', views.HomeView, name='HomeView'),
```

]

The slider is on my base template. When I use extend base.html on another page like otherpage.html then this slider is not work. Because it's not find the source of image.

Comment: either your code or your discription is misleading if try to follow your question then contra. is why you use two html pages when you want to show result on same page? are you using another html template to handle both view? Otherwise send multiple context from single view if your code is this tiny.

Comment: Please read this question one more time

Comment: now you have edited your question which can now be answered

Answer (score 1):

Query the database for both objects in a single function and pass them to the template.

`return render(request,'homepage/homepage.html', {'gallary': gallary, 'lastimage': lastimage, 'slider': slider})`

Answer (score -1):

You need to do something like this -

```
 urlpatterns = [

url(r'^$', views.HomeView, name='HomeView'),

url(r'^$', views.SliderView, name='SliderView'),

# may be you can add this into your view
url(r'^views/$', views.CommonView, name='CommonView'),
]

 def CommonView(request):

    slider = SliderImage.objects.all()
    gallary = GallaryImage.objects.all()
    lastimage = gallary.latest('id')
    return render(request,'homepage/common.html', {'slider': slider ,'gallary': gallary , 'lastimage': lastimage})
```

Inside the **common.html** add two html snippets one contains for 'homepage.html' and other for 'base.html'

PS: You can also do this in your common.html

```
 {% extends "homepage.html" %}

 {% extends "base.html" %}
```

This will extend your templates and put the template params

Comment: this dosen't solve problem he wants both view in single page. It's about using url lookup in template

Comment: Actually I could not explain well. I use this common.html but when I use different apps with this base then it not find the slider.image.

Comment: is this because they might be from different db or they are from different apps ? check settings.py once and include all apps if not

Comment: Yes they are from different apps but same database and different tables. Please see my editing question

Comment: it looks like source of your image file is relative to one of your apps path and that might be the reason why slider not able to find the path. check again your path and if you find this comment useful , mark it as helpful .